# Can jQuery scroll events kill a web page or cause the page to be slow?

Tags: jquery, performance

I tried googling this, I come here when I need further assistance, but I was advised that having too many scroll events on a mobile friendly page via jQuery can overload a page. Is this true? If it does is there documentation supporting this?

Sample snippet is displayed below:

Will these events of hiding and displaying stuff on the webpage overload the system?

```
    //examples of random trigger points
    var triggerHeight1 = 2000;
    var triggerHeight2 = 3000;
    var triggerHeight3 = 4000;

    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
      //get current postion of scroller
      var st = $(this).scrollTop();

      //test to hide or show nav bar
      if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        //scroll down action
        hideNavBar();
      } else {
        // upscroll code
        displayNavBar();
      }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;

    //display hide text
    $(".fadeable").each(function() {
      /* Check the location of each desired element */
      /* If the element is completely within bounds of the window, fade it in */
      //object comes into view (scrolling down)
      if (st >= triggerHeight1) {
        $(this).addClass('visible');
      } else if (st >= triggerHeight2) {
        $(this).addClass('visible');
      } else if (st >= triggerHeight3) {
        $(this).addClass('visible');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('visible');
      }
    });    
});
```

Comment: you can kill a page by causing a stack overflow or make it grind to a stop by using all the ram. i.e. if you do loops on every page scroll event, you wont finish the last loop by the time another one is triggered by the scroll event. You'd only get this effect if you are doing something very wrong

Comment: Short answer is yes, it can. This is because the scroll event fires once for every pixel the UI is updated by. So if you scroll 100px down the page you're potentially running all that code 100 times - loops and all. I'd suggest you look in to debouncing the event handler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan does the example I provided above require this?

Comment: You should always debounce scroll events IMO, but you may be able to get away with it if `hideNavBar()` and `displayNavBar()` are very lightweight functions

Comment: How about when adding the secondary actions of Fade In and Fade Out of Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *can*. Any function that performs heavy actions will slow down or even freeze browser. E.g.:

```
while (true) {
    console.log('ok');
}

console.log('Done');
```

This code will freeze browser, because JS is single-threaded and browser will try to wait until some your code will end execution (it will never end).

---

So when you do `$(selector).scroll()` it will also wait for this action to be executed. If you log every call to this function, will see that it will fire lots of times while scrolling.

I find it's best to use `setTimeout` to reduce browser actions:

```
var timer;

$(document).scroll(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        // Do stuff
    }, 10);
});
```

Comment: This is an infinite while loop and is not applicable to the example I provided.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely!  The best thing to do is use a debounce function, like this...

```
function debounce_event(func,wait,immediate) {
  var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if(!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if(callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
}
```

The parameters are...

1. Function normally called when event fires that you want to throttle/debounce
2. Minimum time to wait (in ms) before triggering the function again
3. Boolean - trigger the function immediately?

EDIT - tying this into your example above...

```
$(window).scroll(debounce_event(function(event) {
  //get current postion of scroller
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  //test to hide or show nav bar
  if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    //scroll down action
    hideNavBar();
  } else {
    // upscroll code
    displayNavBar();
  }
},100,false));
```

So `.scroll` is calling `debounce_event` which calls your function, but it will only call it every 100ms.  The timeout can be varied by the second parameter.

Comment: Similar to what was posted below, I actually find the sample below a little more clearer, how does this function tie in with my snippet above? Trying to see how I can improve the code so that these events are not all firing at once.

Comment: Below? I've edited my answer to give show how to use the function, given your example.

Comment: you don't have to use this debounce if you have your own, but it is a good idea to use a debounce and this example works, so it got my upvote.